# App Script onEdit function calls freezePositiveValues

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to trigger the freezePositiveOutput when a change is made to a value bigger than zero in column A. freezePositiveOutput function works on itself but combined with onedit nothing happens.

```
function onEdit(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var tabValidation = "sheet1";
    var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();

  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 1 && activeCell.getRow() > 1 && ss.getSheetName() == tabValidation){
  freezePositiveOutput();
  }
}

function freezePositiveOutput(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A100");
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] > 0) {
      var cell = range.offset(i, 0, 1, 1);   
      cell.copyTo(cell, {contentsOnly:true});
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: onEdit only responds to user edits.[reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started)

Comment: Thank you, but moving activeCell's range to user editable column, still no result.

Comment: Log says onEdit is triggered and no execution on freezePositiveOutput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(e.range.columnStart==1 && e.range.rowStart>1 && sh.getName()=="Sheet1") {
    freezePositiveOutput(e);
  }
}

function freezePositiveOutput(e){
  var sheet=e.range.getSheet()
  var range=sheet.getRange("A1:A100");
  var values=range.getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
    if (values[i][0]>0) {
      var cell=range.offset(i,0,1,1);   
      cell.copyTo(cell,{contentsOnly:true});
    }
  }
}
```